# why there are two files in my layout folder in android studio while there are only one in of others?

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio has a folder named layout which has two files

- `activity.xml`
- `content.xml`

while the tutorials I have been watching has only one file

- `activity.xml`

How it's going to effect me? What should I do?

Comment: You should be ok. If you want to make changes in your toolbar or appbar use activity.xml and if you want to make changes to your main content use content_xml. Both will work fine. If you see closely activity.xml will be including content.xml so basically they both are the same.

Comment: Both files for single layout. In activity.xml you saw <include> tag to add content.xml. In latest version android studio files are splitted to TWO. activity.xml holds layout for (Toolbar/NavigationView....) & <include> for activity content which holds your entire layout in activity apart from toolbar,navigationdrawer. Note:You can use also single file for layout file.

Answer (score 1):

> My android studio has a folder named layout which has two files activity.xml content.xml while the tutorials I have been watching has only one file activity.xml

The videos that you are watching are using a different version of Android Studio, a different template than the one that you chose when setting up your project, or both.

> How it's going to effect me?

The code in your IDE will be different than that shown in the videos, most likely.

> What should I do?

You could:

- Use educational materials (books, videos, whatever) that are up to date with whatever version of Android Studio that you are using, or
- Try to install the older version of Android Studio used by your videos, or
- Simply watch the videos without attempting to reproduce them step-by-step in Android Studio